# jquery table read input field value

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I made a place management system where you can create, delete or edit placenames.
It's a table where in every row there is a placename an edit button and an delete button. 
At the end of the table there is a "create new place" button. Now when I click on the "create new place" button then I get a new generated row where I can write the new name, cancel the operation and save the operation.

I want know to save an operation which should remove the generated content and create a new row with the name, edit and delete cells. My problem is it only works with one row but if I have two names in operation then the jquery doesnt know on which row I clicked ok to save it.

Example:

generated Row1= Spain

generated Row2= Brasil

click ok in row2, row2 removed by jquery, name of row1 generated in placetable = wrong!

Here The code

```
<head>
  <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".edit").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("edit "+id);
  });
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("delete "+id);
  });
  $("#newbutton").click(function() {
    $("tr:last").after("<tr><td><input style='width: 80%' /></td><td class=ok>OK</td><td class=cancel>Cancel</td></tr>").ready(function() {
      $(".cancel").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
      $(".ok").click(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("tr .edit:last").after("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td class=edit>edit</td><td class=delete>delete</td></tr>");
      });
    });
  })
}); 
  </script>
</head>
<table border=1 id=table>
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>Bombai</td><td id=1 class=edit>edit</td><td id=1 class=delete>delete</td></tr> 
<tr><td>London</td><td id=2 class=edit>edit</td><td id=2 class=delete>delete</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Rom</td><td id=3 class=edit>edit</td><td id=3 class=delete>delete</td></tr> 
</table><label id=newbutton>New Place</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is tested and works...**

Your jquery logic was kind of off. I hope this gets you to understand it a bit better... ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(function() {
  $(".edit").live('click',function() {
    var item = $(this).attr("rel");
    alert("edit "+item);
    return false;
  });
  $(".delete").live('click',function() {
    var item = $(this).attr("item");
    alert("delete "+id);
    return false;
  });
  $(".cancel").live("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
  });
  $(".ok").live('click',function() {                      
    var name = $(this).parent().siblings().find('input[type="text"]').val();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    $("tr:last").after("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>delete</a></td></tr>");
    return false;
  });
  $("#newbutton").click(function() {
    $("tr:last").after("<tr><td><input type='text' style='width: 80%' /></td><td><input type='button' class='ok' value='OK' /></td><td><input type='button' class='cancel' value='Cancel' /></td></tr>")
  })
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" id="table">
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bombai</td>
        <td rel="1"><a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
        <td rel="1"><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>London</td>
        <td rel="2"><a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
        <td rel="2"><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Rom</td>
        <td rel="3"><a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
        <td rel="3"><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
<button id="newbutton">Add New Place</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with a complete solution, I appreciate it very much!

I have made now three new rows with your script but when I click OK they appear at the end of the table. Isn't there a way to make them appear at the end of the editable rows. I tried to change $("tr:last") to $("tr .edit:last") but then when I click OK the rows wont appear :( Do you have maybe a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, id - must be unique within the page!
How are you editing your rows? There are no such code here. Could you add it too?
And small tip, you can mark selected row with some class ('editing') on edit click (but before you should remove this class from any other row) and this will help you to find out which row is in editing state.

EDIT:
Also you can use one of the existing plugins:

```
* Flexigrid: http://flexigrid.info/
* jQuery Grid: http://www.trirand.com/blog/
* jqGridView: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGridView
* Ingrid: http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/
```

jQuery Grid (#2 above) supports editable cells, and has very good documentation and samples on the website. I recommend to have a look at it at first.

Comment: I havent yet made the edit and delete part. When I can create new places which are saved correctly into the placetable, then I will go over to this task.

Comment: What about to use some existing jQuery pluguns which will provide you with all this functionality? Check out update of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a well structured plugin list i am going to check them out!

If there is no way around the problem without a plugin then I will take these into consideration. I know that they can help you to get rid of very much work but I wan't to use as little as possible the plugins so that other people don't have to learn new syntax of plugins or get disorted when looking at my code ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues going on here.

The first is the id's. These need to be unique especially if your using them as references in your javascript. Since your generated rows don't include any id's anyways, I would just remove those completely. If you really want them though, you can write something like "id='delete_1'" which will differentiate them.

Second, you're using the live callback binding function within a click callback function. This means that every time you click the "new" button, it tries to bind your callbacks again. I'm not 100% sure that there's a side-effect for doing this way, but the reason for 'live' is that it will automatically bind the callback to any generated html so you don't have to do it manually.

I would recommend moving the ".cancel" and ".ok" click binding calls outside that one function. Bind the ".ok" click callback using live. After you've made these changes it might help with your problem.

If it doesn't help, use firebug to figure out why jquery is referencing the wrong row on save.